# Rxjava large no. of Iteration then skip the records

Tags: android, rx-java

I am stuck in a process in my current project. I can't talk much about that project, That's why i am explaining the part where i got stuck.

There are a lot of records in the project let's say 2 Million and i want to iterate them all.

i tried to iterate them by many ways, in my case it skipped some records and if some error occurred then i want to return the records which successfully iterated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think i faced this issue earlier. Below code will help you out for this purpose.

```
private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
fun thenAllValuesAreBufferedAndReceived() {
    val observable = Observable.rangeLong(0,10000)
    val testSubscriber = observable
    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .buffer(500)
    //.subscribe(::println)
    .subscribeWith(object :FlowableSubscriber<List<Long>>{
    override fun onComplete() {
    println("Flowable OnComplete")
    }

    override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
    println("Flowable onSubscribe")
    s.request(20)

    }

    override fun onNext(t: List<Long>?) {
    println("Flowable onNext $t")
    }

    override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
    println("Flowable onError")
    }

    })
}
```

Override onDistroy method and clear compositeDisposable by the below code. This will make your app crash free.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    compositeDisposable.clear()
    compositeDisposable.dispose()
}
```

Comment: what does any of this have to do with the question

Comment: This answer will help for less data loss. As we made a batch of 500 each.